# For loop over regex matches in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, loops

I'm very slowly learning Javascript and am having difficulty implementing a `for` loop over regex matches.

I'm working in an `express.js` setup, with the following in my `index.js`

```
var express = require('express');

var router = express.Router();

// the text block against which I am running the regex

var para = "We have insisted on strict scrutiny in every context, even for so-called “benign” racial classifications, such as race-conscious university admissions policies, see Grutter v. Bollinger, 539 U.S. 306, 326 (2003), race-based preferences in government contracts, see Adarand, supra, at 226, and race-based districting intended to improve minority representation, see Shaw v. Reno, 509 U.S. 630, 650 (1993). Daniel added the following test case to the string: Crawford v. Washington, 123 U.S. 123, 123 (2016)."

// regex

var regex = /(\w+\sv.\s\w+,\s\d*\s?[\w.]*[\d,\s]*\(\d{4}\))/ig;
var regexTwo = /\w+\s/ig;

// Store the matches

var matches = para.match(regex);
var matchesTwo = para.match(regexTwo);

// the offending loop

for (var i = 0; i < matches.length; i += 1) {

    router.get('/', function(req, res) {

        res.render('index', { matches, matchesTwo, i }) });

};

module.exports = router;
```

I'm using Jade for the HTML and my `index.jade` file looks like this:

```
extends layout

block content

    body
        h1 CaseSpy
        p I found the following U.S. cases in the text you provided me with:
        ul
            li #{matches}

        p I found the following other terms in the text you provided me with:
        ul
            li #{matchesTwo}
```

The code works, insofar as it matches what I want it to match against. The problem I'm having is that all of the matches are getting bundles up on the same line, so the html output looks like this:

**Output**

I found the following U.S. cases in the text you provided me with:

- Grutter v. Bollinger, 539 U.S. 306, 326 (2003),Shaw v. Reno, 509 U.S. 630, 650 (1993),Crawford v. Washington, 123 U.S. 123, 123 (2016)

The output I'm looking for is:

**Desired Output**

I found the following U.S. cases in the text you provided me with:

- Grutter v. Bollinger, 539 U.S. 306, 326 (2003)
- Shaw v. Reno, 509 U.S. 630, 650 (1993)
- Crawford v. Washington, 123 U.S. 123, 123 (2016)

I've tinkered with the `for` loop endlessly and have tried this sort of method but keep hitting errors:

```
for (var i = 0; i < matches.length; i += 1) {
  document.body.innerHTML += matches[i] + '<br>';
}
```

I just can't seem to crack this. I know I'm doing something fundamentally wrong, I just don't know what.

Many thanks.

Comment: can you post your error??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Miguel said, I believe the issue may be more with your Jade code than with JavaScript. You are trying to put all matches inside a single `li` like so: `li #{matches}`.

What if you try something like this:

```
ul
each item in matches
  li= item
```

Answer (score 2):

not very familiar with Jade, but it looks like you're not unpacking the {matches}. This might help: https://pugjs.org/language/iteration.html   [From what I can tell Jade was renamed to Pug?]

Comment: "Jade was renamed to Pug?" Yes.